# control of Internet Explorer with win32com.client

Tags: python, win32com

i use win32com.client for control Ie but i can't refresh my Ie pages 
i want know how can i refresh Ie Pages when i'm using win32com.client
this is my code :

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import time
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        ie = Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.visible = 1
        ie.Navigate("https://google.com")
```

**Every time a new page opens, but even if Google content. If it is changed, the the new opened page will not refresh**

Comment: Wouldn't this information be found in the documentation?

Comment: Well, first up, it opens a new window every time, because you Dispatch a new client each interval. I assume you want to to refresh whatever page is already opened instead, right?

Comment: yes it's right , I want to to refresh whatever page.